# search array for key PHP

Tags: php, arrays

```
function returnStatus($status)
{
    $supportStatus = [
        0 => 'open',
        1 =>'half closed',
        9 => 'closed',
    ];

    $key = array_search($status, $supportStatus);
    return $supportStatus[$key];
}
```

My script returns 0 (open), even if I sent 9 as int to the function.

Comment: What are you setting as `$status` calling `returnStatus`?

Comment: $status is int (number).

Comment: Wouldn't you need to pass through `open`, `closed` as `array_search` searches the array values for a text match?

Comment: as `array_search` searches? Don't understand what you mean.

Comment: you are passing the key, yet `array_search()` search on value, not key

Comment: If you're calling for example `returnStatus(0)` then `array_search` will search the array for the value `0`, this function works by checking the values i.e. `open` and returning the key which would be `0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is the [`array_key_exists()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php)

```
function returnStatus($status){

    $supportStatus = [
        0 => 'open',
        1 =>'half closed',
        9 => 'closed',
    ];

    $key = array_key_exists($status, $supportStatus);
    return $supportStatus[$key];
}
```

Furthermore you **donot** even need to do that jugglery, if eventually you are interested in the value stored in that key's location.

I'd just do it in one line as below..

```
echo isset($supportStatus[$status]) ? $supportStatus[$status]: false;
```

or with assignment operator

```
$output = isset($supportStatus[$status]) ? $supportStatus[$status]: '';
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is what you're looking for,

```
function searchColor($color){
    $array = array(0 => 'blue', 1 => 'red', 2 => 'green', 3 => 'red');
    $key = array_search($color, $array); 
    return $array[$key];    
}
echo searchColor('blue');
```

Update your code and see if it works, [here is the reference](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php).